# Samba Load Error Upon Startup

Tags: 14.04, networking, samba, upstart

I am facing an issue with every time I freshly start my server the samba service doesn't function properly. I can't connect to the network shares, and can't browse it via its IP.

It is a Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop LTS. I am not using the server edition, I just installed all the services on top of the OS.

Additional Services:

- Ajenti Server Admin
- UFW
- DDNS
- OPEN-SSH
- LEMP

---

I use the command:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

And it restores itself. I created a cron job for @onreboot, but it doesn't execute.

I looked at the samba.log and this caught my eye:

```
[2016/09/18 15:10:29.747204,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_incomingdgrams.c:304(process_local_master_announce)
      process_local_master_announce: Server JUELZ-LAPTOP at IP 192.168.1.69 is announcing itself as a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP and we think we are master. Forcing election.
```

---

Here is the rest of the Log:

```
[2016/09/18 15:10:29.747204,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_incomingdgrams.c:304(process_local_master_announce)
  process_local_master_announce: Server JUELZ-LAPTOP at IP 192.168.1.69 is announcing itself as a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP and we think we are master. Forcing election.
[2016/09/18 15:10:29.747398,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:150(unbecome_local_master_success)
  *****

  Samba name server HFD-SERVER has stopped being a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 192.168.1.93

  *****
[2016/09/18 15:10:46.766304,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****

  Samba name server HFD-SERVER is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 192.168.1.93

  *****
[2016/09/18 15:10:46.766557,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_browsesync.c:354(find_domain_master_name_query_fail)
  find_domain_master_name_query_fail:
  Unable to find the Domain Master Browser name WORKGROUP<1b> for the workgroup WORKGROUP.
  Unable to sync browse lists in this workgroup.
```

---

Also not sure why its doing this:

```
Unable to find the Domain Master Browser name WORKGROUP<1b> for the workgroup WORKGROUP.
Unable to sync browse lists in this workgroup.
```

---

I looked at my Mom's laptop and there is nothing on there that is broadcasting anything, and it is also a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro.

---

**Here is my Samba Config Code:**

```
[global]
netbios name=HFD-SERVER
server string=Samba file and print server
workgroup=Workgroup
security=user
hosts allow=127. 192.168.1.
interfaces=127.0.0.1/8 192.168.1.0/24
bind interfaces only=yes
printcap name=cups
load printers=yes
cups options=raw
printing=cups
guest account=smbguest
log file=/var/log/samba/samba.log
max log size=1000
null passwords=no
username level=6
password level=6
encrypt passwords=yes
unix password sync=yes
socket options=TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
local master=yes
domain master=no
preferred master=yes
domain logons=no
os level=33
logon drive=m:
logon home=\\%L\homes\%u
logon path=\\%L\profiles\%u
logon script=%G.bat
time server=no
name resolve order=wins lmhosts bcast
wins support=yes
wins proxy=no
dns proxy=no
preserve case=yes
short preserve case=yes
client use spnego=no
client signing=no
client schannel=no
server signing=no
server schannel=no
nt pipe support=yes
nt status support=yes
allow trusted domains=no
obey pam restrictions=yes
enable spoolss=yes
client plaintext auth=no
disable netbios=no
follow symlinks=no
update encrypted=yes
pam password change=no
passwd chat timeout=120
hostname lookups=no
username map=/etc/samba/smbusers
passdb backend=tdbsam
passwd program=/usr/bin/passwd '%u'
passwd chat=*New*password* %n\n *ReType*new*password* %n\n *passwd*changed*\n
add user script=/usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -c 'Samba User Account' -s /dev/null '%u'
add user to group script=/usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -c 'Samba User Account' -s /dev/null -g '%g' '%u'
add group script=/usr/sbin/groupadd '%g'
delete user script=/usr/sbin/userdel '%u'
delete user from group script=/usr/sbin/userdel '%u' '%g'
delete group script=/usr/sbin/groupdel '%g'
add machine script=/usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -g sambamachines -c 'Samba Machine Account' -s /dev/null -M '%u'
machine password timeout=120
idmap uid=16777216-33554431
idmap gid=16777216-33554431
template shell=/dev/null
winbind use default domain=yes
winbind separator=@
winbind cache time=360
winbind trusted domains only=yes
winbind nested groups=no
winbind nss info=no
winbind refresh tickets=no
winbind offline logon=no

[homes]
comment=Home Directories
path=/home
valid users=%U
read only=no
available=yes
browseable=yes
writable=yes
guest ok=no
public=no
printable=no
locking=no
strict locking=no

[netlogon]
comment=Network Logon Service
path=/var/lib/samba/netlogon
read only=no
available=yes
browseable=yes
writable=no
guest ok=no
public=no
printable=no
locking=no
strict locking=no

[profiles]
comment=User Profiles
path=/var/lib/samba/profiles
read only=no
available=yes
browseable=yes
writable=yes
guest ok=no
public=no
printable=no
create mode=0600
directory mask=0700
locking=no
strict locking=no

[printers]
comment=All Printers
path=/var/spool/samba
browseable=yes
writable=no
guest ok=no
public=no
printable=yes
locking=no
strict locking=no

[pdf-documents]
path=/var/lib/samba/pdf-documents
comment=Converted PDF Documents
admin users=%U
available=yes
browseable=yes
writeable=yes
guest ok=yes
locking=no
strict locking=no

[pdf-printer]
path=/tmp
comment=PDF Printer Service
printable=yes
guest ok=yes
use client driver=yes
printing=bsd
print command=/usr/bin/gadmin-samba-pdf %s %u
lpq command=
lprm command=

[Shared]
path = /Shared
comment = Shared Drive
#valid users = juelz mike harley
#write list = juelz mike harley
valid users = @Shared
write list = @Shared
admin users = harley
directory mask = 0770
create mode = 0770
force group = Shared
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
public = yes
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no

[127.0.0.1]
path = /srv/localhost
comment = Web Files
valid users = @www-data
write list = @www-data
admin users = @www-data
directory mask = 0770
create mode = 0770
force group = www-data
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no
```

I performed a testparm and no errors occur and in fact the service and shares work perfectly after being reset. It hangs up from time to time which I am not sure if it is a side effect.

Any help would be much appreciated.